# How to fix string ' ' convert to float error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

my code is doing searches, but whenever it comes across the data [00:00] this error occurs below, and I need to convert the string to float because I have to do calculations.

I tried using a method of converting elements, {' ':"00:00"} but it didn't work either
tempo is a string with clock values
tempc is for convert string to make calculations

```
tempo = [my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "ml1-SoccerClock_Clock ")][0]
    esc = [my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ml1-StatsColumn_MiniCornerWrapper")]
    tempc = convertElements(tempo, {' ':"01:00",NULL:"01:00"}) 
    tempc = float(tempo.split(':')[0])
```

Error is this

```
tempc = float(tempo.split(':')[0])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

how to fix this ?

Comment: what you want in case of empty string ?

Comment: is a string that stores the time of the games, then when a game has not started yet, its time is 00:00 and then the value of the class is empty, I would like to prevent it from reading games that have not started yet.  
The code is analyzing all games perfectly, but if there are any that haven't started yet, it gives this error

Comment: then you can use try : float(tempo.split(':')[0])and except ValueError and inside except ValueError you can use __pass__

Answer (score 0):

It depends what value you want to attribute to an empty string. If an empty string should equate to zero then you can do this:

```
tempc = float(tempo.split(':')[0] or 0)
```